# Actor per request in Akka HTTP. How to integrate it with Route directives?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm struggling to get this working, can you please advise?

```
def perRequestActor(message: RestMessage): Route = {
  // Compiler error Type mismatch: found (RequestContext) => ActorRef, required Route
  ctx: RequestContext => system.actorOf(propsCreator(ctx, message), "per-req-actor")
}
val route: Route = 
get {
  perRequestActor(new RestMessage("someVal"))
}
```

How can I resolve that compiler error and keep using the tell pattern to complete the request? Please note I'm not using Spray. Using akka-http

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036644/how-does-spray-routing-httpservice-dispatch-requests

Comment: I would have done it a while ago if I was using Spray. It is complicated with akka http. Please take a look at my comments with johny. Thanks

Comment: Could you resolve this issue, I'm struggling with it myself?

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the method `perRequestActor` is Route, but you are returning `ActorRef`.

From documentation

> ```
> type Route = RequestContext => Future[RouteResult]
> ```
>
> It's a simple alias for a function taking a RequestContext as parameter and returning a Future[RouteResult].
>
> Generally when a route receives a request (or rather a RequestContext
>   for it) it can do one of these things:
>
> ```
> Complete the request by returning the value of requestContext.complete(...)
> Reject the request by returning the value of requestContext.reject(...) (see Rejections)
> Fail the request by returning the value of requestContext.fail(...) or by just throwing an exception (see Exception Handling)
> Do any kind of asynchronous processing and instantly return a Future[RouteResult] to be eventually completed later on
> ```

For using `tell` pattern you can send messages to the actor that you created.

```
val actor = system.actorOf(propsCreator(ctx, message), "per-req-actor")
actor ! SomeMessage
```

Documentation for the latest version(1.0) of `akka-http` is more clear and has a slightly different signature. If you just started to learn you should probably use that.

Comment: But then how can I complete the request after `actor ! SomeMessage` result returns? Your last code snippet can't be place inside route directives unless it returns Route (`Future[RouteResult]`). Can you please put it inside Route directives for `GET` request for example?

Comment: If it returns some result, then use `ask` pattern, instead of `tell`, which returns a `Future`. Then you can map that `Future` to a `Future[RouteResult]`.

Comment: The whole thing is about avoiding `ask` :( I want to make it all with `tell`

Comment: If you are using `actor ! SomeMessage`, then nothing will return. If that is what you wanted, then you can wrap your response in `Future.successful`.

Comment: This won't work with `tell`. The point is to pass `ctx: RequestContext` to the `PerRequestActor ref` and complete it ( `ctx.complete` ) from within that actor. Would you be able to help with some code to show how I can achieve this in the `route` directives (in my example above)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue trying to port the spray code in https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/spray-actor-per-request to akka http.  It seems that the `perRequest` method in the `PerRequest` trait should return a `Future[RouteResult]` which will be completed in the newly created actor.  Is the direction of my thinking correct? If so how to achieve that?

Comment: @The Dude, which version are you porting to? Op dint want to use `ask pattern`, what exactly is the problem you are facing? You may have to ask a separate question.

Comment: @johny I'm still using `akka-http-experimental` 1.0 (I've seen there is a 2.0-M1 available but it's bit too early for me I guess.  I'm actually only starting so maybe it's a good idea to move to the 2.0 asap.  What do you think? I've asked a question about tell vs. ask and per-request-actors on the Akka news group.

Comment: @The Dude, If you just started learning, use `2.0-M1`. As they are constantly changing signatures, it would be better start with the latest version. By the time you are ready to use it, you wont have a lot to catch up. there are a lot of `tell vs ask` questions here itself.